# Rewrite conditional distribution that is an inequality as a function

Tags: functions, inequality, conditional-probability

How do I rewrite a conditional distribution that is an inequality as a function of another variable?

The problem I have been posed is the following:

Given

$F_u(y) = \mathbb{P}[A-u \le y | A > u]$

Show that this can be rewritten as

$F(x) = 1 - (1-F(u))(1-F_u(x-u))$

Comment: If you know the definition of conditional probability you should be able to start with RHS and get LHS with simple algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your welcome. If I'm honest, I cannot expand on this further because this is all the information I am given. I'm on a finance course, would that count as context? I don't have a statistical background and this has kind of thrown me because I think it is expected that I would have more prior knowledge.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've seen the definition as $\mathbb{P} (B|A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \text{and} B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$ but I don't understand how this relates to $F(x)$?

Comment: $F_u(y)=\frac {F(u+y)-f(u)} {1-F(u)}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh I see. So $u + y$ is equivalent to $x - u$ and I just rearrange. That's great. Thank you for your help.